# To determine the number of reducers in Hive "order by" clause

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a 2.6 MB sized CSV file. I created a hive table and loaded the csv file in it.

Now, if I write a query as "select * from abc order by a;" , mapreduce used 1 reducer. How did it identify the number of reducer as 1? Did it use the default value "1" or something else?

In general, how does hive decide how many reducers to use in an "order by", "sort by" or "group by" clause?

Answer (score 0):

It goes with data size, default is 1 per 1GB, its regulated by this property:

```
hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer
```

If you want to have more reducers set it with this:

```
mapred.reduce.tasks
```

Full list of settings with explanations can be find [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/tags/release-0.5.0/conf/hive-default.xml).

Comment: that config however does not affect the number of reducers used for `order by`. for `order by` it is always set to 1 and that's reasonable

Answer (score 0):

Number of reducers in Hive is calculated using `hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer` property where 1GB (1000000000 bytes) is it's default value. 
You can configure number of reducers by changing the above mentioned property. Also you need to set the constant number of reducers for a job by the property `mapred.reduce.tasks`

// hive-site.xml

```
<property>
   <name>hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer</name>
   <value>xxxxxxx</value>
</property>
```

// console

```
$ hive -e "set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=xxxxxxx"
```